# How can i block a site on Chrome by using HTML?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to block a site on chrome by using html. It shows a pop-up. If i press OK, it blocks the site but if i press cancel, it continues the site. How can i fix this ?

Here is the code and the screenshot;

---

```html
    <html>
<script>
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))  //If Internet Explorer, return version number
{
  //alert('IE ' + parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
var test="Hi there";
}

else {
var result = confirm('Please just use Internet Explorer !!');
}

if (result)
    window.location.replace("ie_browser.html");
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

[Screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NH2V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The JavaScript `confirm()` apparently returns `true` if the user selects "OK", and false for "Cancel". You really don't need `var result`, since you want to change `window.location` regardless of the user's response to the `confirm()`. I put the `window.location` statement in the `else` block, after the `confirm()`, since you don't need to check result.

```html
<html>
    <script>
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))  // If Internet Explorer, return version number
    {
        // alert('IE ' + parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
        var test="Hi there";
    }
    else {
        var result = confirm('Please just use Internet Explorer !!');
        window.location.replace("ie_browser.html");
    }
    
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```